# Can't reset the values in Select block

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, react-select, yup

I have implemented a form component and that I have added two Select blocks which are made using react-select. I am using Formik and Yup for form control. But, I am not able to reset the value of Select blocks after submit although other form block's values get reset. Below I have given the code (I am using Tailwind and DaisyUI for CSS):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import Select from "react-select";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";


import certificatetagOptions from "@/content/certificateTags.json"
import serviceTagOptions from "@/content/serviceTags.json"

export const FormQuote = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const pageName = router.pathname.split('/')[1]

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

    const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phoneno: "",
        orgname: "",
        selectedservicestags: [],
        selectedcertificatetags: [],
        numemp: '',
        additionalComments: "",
    });

    const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup
            .string()
            .required('Full Name is required'),
        email: Yup
            .string()
            .email()
            .required('Email is required'),
        phoneno: Yup
            .string()
            .matches(/^\d{10}$/, 'Phone number must be 10 digits')
            .required('Phone number is required'),
        orgname: Yup
            .string()
            .required('Organization Name is required'),
        selectedservicestags: Yup
            .array()
            .min(1, 'Atleast one service is required')
            .required('Service is required'),
        selectedcertificatetags: Yup
            .array()
            .min(1, 'Atleast one certificate is required')
            .required('Certificate is required'),
        numemp: Yup
            .number()
            .min(1, 'Atleast one employee is required')
            .required('Number of employees is required'),
        additionalComments: Yup.string(),
    });

    const successModal = () => {
        return (
            <div className="modal modal-open modal-bottom sm:modal-middle">
                <div className="modal-box">
                    <h3 className="font-bold text-lg">Congratulations random Internet user!</h3>
                    <p className="py-4">You've been selected for a chance to get one year of subscription to use Wikipedia for free!</p>
                    <div className="modal-action">
                        <label htmlFor="my-modal-6" className="btn" onClick={() => setIsSubmitted(false)}>Yay!</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (values: object, { resetForm }: any) => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        try {
            await axios.post("/api/form", { pageName, ...values });
            setIsSubmitted(true);
            resetForm();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        setIsLoading(false)
    };

    return (
        <>
            {isSubmitted ? successModal() : null}
            <div className="hero max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto bg-gradient-to-b from-slate-900 to-white bg-opacity-10 rounded-xl">
                <div className="hero-overlay rounded-xl"></div>
                <div className="flex flex-col w-full">
                    <h1 className="text-white text-lg md:text-xl lg:text-2xl font-bold my-10 mx-10 text-center">Ready to elevate your business to the next level? Elevate your business with our tailored certification solutions. Get a free quote today by filling out the form below and take the first step towards certification excellence.</h1>
                    <div className="card w-full shadow-2xl bg-base-100 rounded-none">
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={handleSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                                {(props) => (
                                    <Form className="">
                                        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                                            <div className="form-control">
                                                <label className="label" htmlFor="name">
                                                    <span className="label-text">Full Name</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <Field type="text" placeholder="Full Name" className={props.errors.name && props.touched.name ? "input input-error" : "input input-bordered"} id="name" name="name" />
                                                {props.errors.name && props.touched.name ? <div className="ml-1 text-sm text-red-500">{props.errors.name}</div> : null}
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-control">
                                                <label className="label" htmlFor="email">
                                                    <span className="label-text">Email</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <Field type="email" placeholder="Email" className={props.errors.email && props.touched.email ? "input input-error" : "input input-bordered"} id="email" name="email" />
                                                {props.errors.email && props.touched.email ? <div className="ml-1 text-sm text-red-500">{props.errors.email}</div> : null}
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-control">
                                                <label className="label" htmlFor="phoneno">
                                                    <span className="label-text">Phone Number</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <Field type="tel" placeholder="Example: 1234567890" className={props.errors.phoneno && props.touched.phoneno ? "input input-error" : "input input-bordered"} id="phoneno" name="phoneno" />
                                                {props.errors.phoneno && props.touched.phoneno ? <div className="ml-1 text-sm text-red-500">{props.errors.phoneno}</div> : null}
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-control">
                                                <label className="label" htmlFor="orgname">
                                                    <span className="label-text">Organisation Name</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <Field type="text" placeholder="Organisation Name" className={props.errors.orgname && props.touched.orgname ? "input input-error" : "input input-bordered"} id="orgname" name="orgname" />
                                                {props.errors.orgname && props.touched.orgname ? <div className="ml-1 text-sm text-red-500">{props.errors.orgname}</div> : null}
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-control">
                                                <label className="label" htmlFor="numemp">
                                                    <span className="label-text">Number of Employees</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <Field type="number" placeholder="Number of Employees" className={props.errors.numemp && props.touched.numemp ? "input input-error" : "input input-bordered"} id="numemp" name="numemp" />
                                                {props.errors.numemp && props.touched.numemp ? <div className="ml-1 text-sm text-red-500">{props.errors.numemp}</div> : null}
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-control">
                                                <label className="label" htmlFor="selectedservicestags">
                                                    <span className="label-text">Type of Service(s)</span>
                                                </label>
                                                {props.errors.selectedservicestags && props.touched.selectedservicestags ?
                                                    <>
                                                        <Select
                                                            id="selectedservicestags"
                                                            instanceId="selectedservicestags"
                                                            isMulti
                                                            options={serviceTagOptions.map((tag) => ({
                                                                value: tag.key,
                                                                label: tag.key,
                                                                ...tag
                                                            }))}
                                                            styles={{
                                                                control: (state) => ({
                                                                    display: 'flex',
                                                                    borderColor: state.isFocused || state.isSelected ? 'red' : 'red',
                                                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                                                    borderRadius: 8,
                                                                    minHeight: '3em',
                                                                    color: state.isFocused || state.isSelected ? 'black' : 'black',
                                                                }),
                                                            }}
                                                            placeholder="Select service(s)"
                                                            onChange={(tags) => props.setFieldValue('selectedservicestags', tags.map(tag => tag.value))}
                                                        />
                                                        <div className="ml-1 text-sm text-red-500">{props.errors.selectedservicestags}</div>
                                                    </> : <Select
                                                        id="selectedservicestags"
                                                        instanceId="selectedservicestags"
                                                        isMulti
                                                        options={serviceTagOptions.map((tag) => ({
                                                            value: tag.key,
                                                            label: tag.key,
                                                            ...tag,
                                                        }))}
                                                        styles={{
                                                            control: (state) => ({
                                                                display: 'flex',
                                                                borderColor: state.isFocused || state.isSelected ? 'black' : 'light-grey',
                                                                borderWidth: 1,
                                                                borderRadius: 8,
                                                                minHeight: '3em',
                                                                color: state.isFocused || state.isSelected ? 'black' : 'light-grey',
                                                            }),
                                                        }}
                                                        placeholder="Select service(s)"
                                                        onChange={(tags) => props.setFieldValue('selectedservicestags', tags.map(tag => tag.value))}
                                                    />
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-control">
                                                <label className="label" htmlFor="selectedcertificatetags">
                                                    <span className="label-text">Type of Certification(s)</span>
                                                </label>
                                                {props.errors.selectedcertificatetags && props.touched.selectedcertificatetags ?
                                                    <>
                                                        <Select
                                                            id="selectedcertificatetags"
                                                            instanceId="selectedcertificatetags"
                                                            isMulti
                                                            options={certificatetagOptions.map((tag) => ({
                                                                value: tag.key,
                                                                label: tag.key,
                                                                ...tag
                                                            }))}
                                                            styles={{
                                                                control: (state) => ({
                                                                    display: 'flex',
                                                                    borderColor: state.isFocused || state.isSelected ? 'red' : 'red',
                                                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                                                    borderRadius: 8,
                                                                    minHeight: '3em',
                                                                    color: state.isFocused || state.isSelected ? 'black' : 'black',
                                                                }),
                                                            }}
                                                            placeholder="Select certificate(s)"
                                                            onChange={(tags) => props.setFieldValue('selectedcertificatetags', tags.map(tag => tag.value))}
                                                        />
                                                        <div className="ml-1 text-sm text-red-500">{props.errors.selectedcertificatetags}</div>
                                                    </> : <Select
                                                        id="selectedcertificatetags"
                                                        instanceId="selectedcertificatetags"
                                                        isMulti
                                                        options={certificatetagOptions.map((tag) => ({
                                                            value: tag.key,
                                                            label: tag.key,
                                                            ...tag,
                                                        }))}
                                                        styles={{
                                                            control: (state) => ({
                                                                display: 'flex',
                                                                borderColor: state.isFocused || state.isSelected ? 'black' : 'light-grey',
                                                                borderWidth: 1,
                                                                borderRadius: 8,
                                                                minHeight: '3em',
                                                                color: state.isFocused || state.isSelected ? 'black' : 'light-grey',
                                                            }),
                                                        }}
                                                        placeholder="Select certificate(s)"
                                                        onChange={(tags) => props.setFieldValue('selectedcertificatetags', tags.map(tag => tag.value))}
                                                    />
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-control mt-4">
                                            <label className="label" htmlFor="additionalComments">
                                                <span className="label-text">Additional Comments/Questions</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <Field as="textarea" className="textarea textarea-bordered" placeholder="Additional Comments/Questions" id="additionalComments" name="additionalComments" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-control mt-8">
                                            <button type="submit" className={
                                                props.errors.numemp && props.touched.numemp ||
                                                    props.errors.orgname && props.touched.orgname ||
                                                    props.errors.phoneno && props.touched.phoneno ||
                                                    props.errors.email && props.touched.email ||
                                                    props.errors.name && props.touched.name ||
                                                    props.errors.selectedcertificatetags && props.touched.selectedcertificatetags ?
                                                    "btn btn-disabled" : "btn btn-primary"
                                            } disabled={isLoading}>{isLoading ?
                                                <div className="inline-block h-8 w-8 animate-spin rounded-full border-4 border-solid border-current border-r-transparent align-[-0.125em] motion-reduce:animate-[spin_1.5s_linear_infinite]" role="status">
                                                    <span className="!absolute !-m-px !h-px !w-px !overflow-hidden !whitespace-nowrap !border-0 !p-0 ![clip:rect(0,0,0,0)]">Loading...</span>
                                                </div> : 'Submit'}</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </Form>
                                )}
                            </Formik>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Does anybody know how to change the code to fix this issue?